# Button does not get centered in block-level container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

Why is it that a button placed inside a `flex` container is centered by using `margin : 0px auto;`, but a button placed inside a normal container is not?

Also, what can I do to center the button in the normal container (I cannot change my HTML, so a CSS solution would be appreciated.)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
}
.normal-container {
  background: green;
}
button {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <button>Button in flex</button>
</div>
<div class="normal-container">
  <button>Button in normal</button>
</div>
```

jsFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/r8h3d9wy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align:center` on the parent as inputs/buttons are inline level elements.

`margin:0 auto` in flex-containers works because that's the way alignment works on flex-items. It effectively removes the inline level nature and makes it a flex-child.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: center;
}
.normal-container {
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <button>Button in flex</button>
</div>
<div class="normal-container">
  <button>Button in normal</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I change it to `display:inline-block` or `display:block` instead?

Comment: Sure, if you want but depending on your structure that might have other effects.

Answer (score 1):

In normal containers, `margin: 0px auto` is only applied to block elements. Try this:

```
button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Normally, block elements have a width of 100% by default. In this case it's not a problem because you use a button. Otherwise you would have to set the width to center the element.

Answer (score 1):

With inline-level elements, like [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` compute to 0.

> [**10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced
>   elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#q4)
>
> The `width` property does not apply. A specified value of `auto` for
>   `left`, `right`, `margin-left` or `margin-right` becomes a computed
>   value of `0`.

You can center the `button` element by:

1. Applying `text-align: center` to the parent ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r8h3d9wy/4/)), OR
2. Switching to `display: block` on the button ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r8h3d9wy/3/)).

In the flex container, you're working within a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers), which *blockifies* flex items and permits alignment with [`auto` margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276).

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the computed styles in chrome you will notice that the child elements in the flex container will have `display:block` while the child elements in the normal container will have `display:inline-block`. If you add `display:block` to the CSS for the button it will center the same in both containers.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS code would do the trick. I've made explanations using comments.

```
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  background:yellow;
}

.normal-container{
  background:green;
  text-align: center; /*aligns inline items to center.*/

button{
  margin : auto;
  display: inline; /* Not needed in this case as the button is an inline element naturally. However, if you have a block element, you would use this to make it an inline element. Explanation below. */
}
```

A display:block element takes up all the space to the right or left of it in the parent container. Thus, margin:auto does nothing as there is no margin. Making it an inline element changes this and frees up the margins allowing margin:auto to work.